# How do I substitute a particular IP in a file with Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a list of IPs, I have to transform all the lPs starting with `210.x.x.x` to `10.x.x.x`

For example:

`210.10.10.217.170` ----> `10.10.10.217.170`

Is there any in-line Perl regular expression substitution to do that?

I would like to have this substitution in Perl.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your input file?

Comment: Those aren't valid IP addresses. IP addresses have four parts - these values have five.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use sed instead ?

```
sed -e 's/^210\./10./' yourfile.txt
```

If you really want a perl script :

```
while (<>) { $_ =~ s/^210\./10./; print }
```

Comment: I suspect you want a /g there.   The perl equivalent to that sed is `perl -pe's/^210\./10./' yourfile.txt`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ip =~ s/^210\./10./;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `perl -pe` to iterate over the lines of the file and do a simple substitution:

```
perl -pe 's/^210\./10./' file
```

Or to modify the file in-place:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^210\./10./' file
```

See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) and [s///](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html).

Comment: Please add some explanation along with your code, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Read the IP list file and store in an array
$ipfile = 'ipfile.txt';
open(ipfile) or die "Can't open the file";
@iplist = <ipfile>;
close(ipfile);

# Substitute 210.x IPs and store all IPs into a new array
foreach $_(@iplist)
{
  s/^210\./10\./g;
  push (@newip,$_);
}

# Print the new array
print @newip;
```